# Google approval screen overlaps with status bar

Tags: bug, status-declined, ios-app

Just downloaded the iOS app (0.1.60), when I try to login using Google, the time bar overlaps with the word "Google". Screenshot attached.

[image]

Comment: I wonder if the bug is with Google or Stack Exchange..

Comment: You're seeing this screen in the Google+ app, not the StackExchange app.  I've seen it, it's annoying, but there is literally nothing we can do short of not having Google login to fix this. :)

Comment: @Brian yeah, blame Google. Easy! ;)

Comment: @BrianNickel FWIW I consider that comment an answer I would upvote/accept